# DIV on top of DIV on hover without blinking

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a hover effect like in this example http://usepanda.com/app/
I want to be able to add info on the div once hovered just like they did

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/584/

```
<div class="hover"></div>
<div class="fade" style="display:none"></div>
```

CSS:

```
   .hover{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:yellow;
}
.fade{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:black;    
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("div.hover").hover(
      function () {
        $("div.fade").fadeIn();
      }, 
      function () {
        $("div.fade").fadeOut();
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: GoGo please follow my answer please see below it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/588/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("div.hover").mouseover(
     function () {
      $("div.fade").fadeIn();
     }); 
      $("div.fade").mouseout( function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="hover">
  <div class="fade" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try thiis

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.hover').mouseover(
    function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.fade').fadeIn();
    }
)
$('.fade').mouseout(
    function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.hover').fadeIn();
    }
)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/586/

Comment: is there a better way of doing this or this is the only way? Your answer does work but I just want to know if I can optimize this code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".hover").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.fade').show();
      }
    );
    $(".fade").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.hover').show();
      }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something for starter 
http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/587/

The idea was after the `div.fade` got loaded, the movement of the mouse would trigger the `mouseleave` of the `div.hover`.  All you needed to just write a `mouseover` for the div.hover and a `mouseout` for `div.fade`.

And ofcourse a little `opacity` would do the trick you require